# Не найдена переменная. Хотя значение присвоено

Tags: php

```
include 'magic_quotes.php';
include 'db.php';


$title="YKozhemiaka";

try {
   $result=$pdo->query("SELECT id,title FROM menu");
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    $error="Nie mozna poprać menu".$e->getMessage();
    include 'error.php';
    exit();
}
foreach ($result as $row){
    $menu[]=array('id'=>$row['id'],'title'=>$row['title']);
}
print_r($menu);
echo $menu['title'];
```

ВЫВОД:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас массив `$menu` имеет следующую структуру:

```
$menu = array(
  0 => array('id' => '...', 'title' => '...'),
  1 => array('id' => '...', 'title' => '...'),
  2 => array('id' => '...', 'title' => '...'),
  3 => array('id' => '...', 'title' => '...'),
);
```

Соответственно ключа `title` в массиве `$menu` нет. Он есть у `$menu[0]`, `$menu[1]`, `$menu[2]` и `$menu[3]`.